# Xunit create new instance of Test class for every new Test ( using WebDriver and C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, xunit.net

Is there any way to run multiple tests in same browser using Webdriver (Selenium) using Xunit, , at present xunit launches new browser for every new test , below is the sample code

```
public class Class1

{
    private FirefoxDriver driver;
    public Class1()
    {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElementById("gbqfq").SendKeys("Testing");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElementById("gbqfq").SendKeys("Testing again");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I don't know Selenium, I do know that xUnit.net creates a new instance of your test class for every test method, so that probably explains why you are seeing the behaviour you're reporting: the `driver` field is initialized anew for each test method, because the constructor is invoked every time.

In order to reuse a single `FirefoxDriver` instance, you can use xUnit.net's `IUseFixture<T>` interface:

```
public class Class1 : IUseFixture<FirefoxDriver>
{
    private FirefoxDriver driver;

    public void SetFixture(FirefoxDriver data)
    {
        driver = data;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElementById("gbqfq").SendKeys("Testing");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElementById("gbqfq").SendKeys("Testing again");
    }    
}
```

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest is this needs to be `IUseFixture<IWebDriver>`, so that this allows other drivers to be used (Chrome, Firefox, IE etc). All drivers within Selenium implement `IWebDriver`.

Comment: The `IUseFixture<T>` interface has the generic constraint `T : new()`, so that's unfortunately not going to be possible.

Comment: V neat +1 (tomorrow when I get more votes :D) Didn't ever consider that a third party class (and/or a `Tuple`d set of args) could be used in a `IUseFixture` 'invocaction' directly.

Answer (score 2):

after some investigation able to find the solution here it is and also updated FirefoxDriver to IWebDriver::

```
   public class SampleFixture : IDisposable
   {
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public SampleFixture()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Console.WriteLine("SampleFixture constructor called");

    }

    public IWebDriver InitiateDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       // driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing Fixture");
    }
}

public class Class1 : IUseFixture<SampleFixture>
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    public void SetFixture(SampleFixture data)
    {
        driver = data.InitiateDriver();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys("Testing");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys("Testing again");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IUseFixture` doesn't exist any more and seems replaced by [IClassFixture](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.html). But I can't directly inject the `FirefoxDriver` as posted by @Mark Seemann:

```
public class DashboardCategoryBoxes : IClassFixture<FirefoxDriver> {
    IWebDriver driver;
    public DashboardCategoryBoxes(FirefoxDriver driver) {
        //this.driver = wrapper.Driver;
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

This throw an error

```
 System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class fixture type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver' may only define a single public constructor.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: FirefoxDriver driver)
    ---- Class fixture type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver' may only define a single public constructor.
    ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: FirefoxDriver driver
```

As a workaround, we could create some wrapper class without constructor

```
public class FirefoxWrapper {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    public FirefoxWrapper Driver {
        get { return driver; }
    }
}
```

and fetch the driver from there

```
public class DashboardCategoryBoxes : IClassFixture<FirefoxWrapper> {
    IWebDriver driver;
    public DashboardCategoryBoxes(FirefoxWrapper wrapper) {
        driver = wrapper.Driver;
    }
}
```